# Laravel images 404 not found

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 6.2 application that displays news articles, is showing image, title, and text in a grid.

Images are uploaded in public/images/ folder and accessed using asset('images/image_name.jpg'), image name ar stored in the database.

I have added a new article and uploaded image, everything is the same as was with all other articles.

Now with the last one, there is a problem with displaying image. It shows 404 not found. Now every image I upload on server in this Laravel project public folder I can`t access anymore, shows 404 not found.

- Tried to clear Laravels cache
- Uploaded image on a server outside Laravels public folder, then I can access it.

**UPDATE**

Problem solved, nothing to do with Laravel.

Comment: Did you run `php artisan storage:link`? `asset` is using storage directory, for using it you should run `storage:link` artisan command and also you should upload images in `storages/app/public/images/`

Comment: I`m using asset and all images now are stored in public/images, all older images I have added ar displaying as it should, last image I have uploaded not displaying.

Comment: Check the image path to the image in the URL store to the database. Also check your env("APP_URL") it is storing the correct URL path. Like for localhost: `http://localhost:8080/images/images_name.jpg`

Comment: There is lot of articles, every article is working as it should, only for last added there is this problem. I can`t access it via link. I have even copied older article image link and changed to last uploaded image name and it still shows 404.

Comment: Change `asset('images/image_name.jpg')` to `asset('/images/image_name.jpg')` add a slash before the path. Hope this helps

Comment: How it can help if  I can`t access that image using a full link to it in the browser?

Comment: Can you show the image link stored in the database?

Comment: There is no link stored in database, but only images name with extension, like image_name.jpg, thats it.

Comment: Try this `{{URL::to("images/image_name.jpg")}}`

Comment: Thank you, for trying to solve this, but there was folders structure problem.

Comment: You should access it using storage link `localhost:8080/storage/images/image_name.jpg`

Comment: For getting images with asset also add `storage` before your path: `asset('/storage/iamges/image_name.jpg')`

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/clear', function() {
    
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:cache');
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:clear');
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('view:clear');
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('route:clear');
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('clear-compiled');
    return 'DONE'; 
  });
```

Comment: I have tried this before, and now did it again through terminal, nothing changed.